# Handle some rows differently on upsert -> exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm using Rails 6 and the new `upsert_all` method.

This is super useful, however, there are some questions I have about how to add columns *only* if it's a new record. Take for instance, the `created_at` column.

If the record is new, you would want to add this (as well as any other `null: false` columns without a `default: ...`

But, I also don't want to change `created_at` if I'm updating.

How would I handle this other than removing the column?

Comment: does the created_at value was really updated? Or are you talking about the updated_at column?

Comment: What are you asking again? It wont automatically do timestamps, but It sets every single field is the problem (whereas you would only want to change created_at on insert (if it doesnt exist) but NOT on update in the upsert)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TLDR: Use the `unique_by` parameter

Seeing as `upsert_all` [does not load the model](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods/upsert_all), in order to treat some rows (i.e. db records) differently you'll need to use the `unique_by` parameter along with a database column(s) that has a unique_by clause.

### Full Example

For example, suppose we have a `Book` model that has an id, name and age. I want to both insert a few new books and update the age of one or more books. The `name` column has no default value and cannot be null.

```rb
# books table
# id: 1, name: 'dracula', age: 10
# id: 2, name: 'jane eyre', age: 20
# id: 3, name: 'ulysses', age: 30
```

I could do:

```rb
Book.upsert_all([
  {id: 2, age: 40}, # <- updates this record
  {name: 'war and peace', age: 35 }, # <- new record
  {name: '1984', age: 45} # <- new record
], unique_by: :id)
```

Above, note that I passed the `unique_by: :id` argument. This instructed the database to update these records instead of creating them.

The result would be:

```rb
# books table
# id: 1, name: 'dracula', age: 10
# id: 2, name: 'jane eyre', age: 40
# id: 3, name: 'ulysses', age: 30
# id: 4, name: 'war and peace', age: 35
# id: 5, name: '1984', age: 45
```

I could use any database column as long it has as unique index ([source](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods/upsert_all)). For example, if I had a unique index on the `name` column, this query would give a similar result:

```rb
Book.upsert_all([
  {name: 'jane eyre', age: 40}, # <- updates this record
  {name: 'war and peace', age: 35 }, # <- new record
  {name: '1984', age: 45} # <- new record
], unique_by: :name)
```

Finally, Rails will handle the `updated_at` and `created_at` properties as expected.